# on "The Binding of Isaac: Wrath of The Lamb", how do I unlock the locked challenges?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

How do I unlock challenges in The Binding of Issac: Wrath of The Lamb? So far I only managed to unlock the first 4 challenges. I tried asking around but both my friend and I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I've never played the binding of isaac, but I'm going to go off on a whim and say you need to tell us which challenge you want to unlock. I'm assuming there are several different scenarios to unlock each one, but that's just how a lot of games that _I've_ played work.

Answer (score 0):

The Binding of Issac: Wrath of the Lamb has 10 challenges that you can unlock by beating certain bosses in normal runs of the game. The unlock criteria are as follows:

- Challenges 1-4: Unlocked by default.
- Challenges 5-9: Defeat [Mom](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Mom).
- Challenge 10: Defeat [Issac](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Isaac_(boss)).

For more information about what the different challenges are you can [checkout this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70797/what-are-each-of-the-challenges).

[Source.](https://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/656119-the-binding-of-isaac-the-wrath-of-the-lamb/faqs/65665)